# Jenkins git plugin not setting environment variables

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using jenkins git plugin as shown in below pipeline code(groovy). Checkout is working but the environment variables are not getting set.

```
node(){
   dir("${WORKAREA}") {
               //checkout uses mirror repo to make creation of new repo faster and smaller
               //clean is done after checkout (rsync was doing this part)
               performCheckout(REPO, BRANCH, BITBUCKET_PROJECT_URL, UNIVERSAL_REFERENCE_REPO_PATH)
               sh("env")

   }
}

private void performCheckout(REPOSITORY, BRANCH, String BITBUCKET_PROJECT_URL, String UNIVERSAL_REFERENCE_REPO_PATH) {
   //standard plugin for checkout
   checkout changelog: true,
           poll: false,
           scm: [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                 branches                         : [[name: "refs/remotes/${REPOSITORY}/${BRANCH}"]],
                 doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                 extensions                       : [[$class   : 'CloneOption',
                                                      depth    : 1,
                                                      noTags   : true,
                                                      reference: "${UNIVERSAL_REFERENCE_REPO_PATH}",
                                                      shallow  : false,
                                                     [$class             : 'SparseCheckoutPaths',
                                                      sparseCheckoutPaths: [
                                                              [path: '!/tests/*'],
                                                              [path: '/*']]],
                                                     [$class: 'CleanCheckout', timeout: 40],
                                                     [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 75]],
                 gitTool                          : 'Default', submoduleCfg: [],
                 userRemoteConfigs                : [
                         [credentialsId: 'privatekey',
                          name         : "${REPOSITORY}",
                          url          : "${BITBUCKET_PROJECT_URL}/${REPOSITORY}.git"]
                 ]]
}
```

when i print env(**sh("env")**) in the pipeline it doesn't print GIT_* environment variables. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: git setting environment variables would be new to me, and I'm not sure that Jenkins sets any unless you do it explicitly.  Do you normally have these variables set after git operations?

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes it does, See this https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin#environment-variables